Conditional formatting if cell past date and another cell empty with arrayformula
I'm using a formula to add TRUE/FALSE when the statement is true.

Rather than add this formula to every row (I have over 4000), I want to add it to the 2nd row as an arrayformula. But I write the formula like this:
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(F2:F<=TODAY()-21,F2:F<>"",H2:H = ""))
the formula doens't apply to the entire column.
Expecting arrayformula to apply formula across the entire column.

Using (*) instead of AND Operator
Instead of using the AND operator in your formula, use an asterisk instead. The AND operator does not work with ARRAYFORMULA and the asterisk (*) serves as an equivalent to AND. In this context, it allows you to perform logical AND operations within an ARRAYFORMULA.
You may try this formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F <> "", IF(H2:H = "", TODAY() - F2:F >= 21, H2:H - F2:F > 21), FALSE))

Sample Output:

Reference:
Google Sheets function list

If this resolves your issue, please click the accept button (checkmark icon) on the left and consider upvoting the answer. This helps others in the community with similar questions, find solutions.

Thank you, this is great. Can we modify the formula so it checks if 21 days have passed from the Launch Date date and if the Registered date is blank, the output should be True.

The formula and sample output above was edited. Kindly check if it works on your end.

Thank you. But surely, if the registered column H has a value, then the column G should be blank, not True, because they have registered. We only want a TRUE/FALSE output if the Launch Date has a date. So this formula works for me:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H = "",IF(F2:F <> "",IF(H2:H = "",TODAY() - F2:F >= 21,H2:H - F2:F > 21)),))
